# How do I add fields dynamically in web2py forms?

Tags: web2py

I have a form field(with label "person1"). I would like to add more fields of the same type to add more people. How do I add specific fields dynamically in web2py forms by clicking a button?

Answer (score 0):

Like this?
http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/11/jquery-and-ajax#Conditional-fields-in-forms

I want to add something similar to a webapp, I have no code to show atm because is not my first priority, there are different tables involved and I think I will need to use an SQLFORM.factory with custom fields set to css display:none by default. I will then use jquery to show them up on demand and eventually writing all to DB.

But the example on the book seems like a good way to start exploring.

Anyway, if fields as in form's fields try this...

This in a model:

```
db.define_table("people", Field("person", "string"), format='%(person)s')
```

This in a controller:

```
def add_person():
    form = SQLFORM.factory(db.people,
        buttons=[INPUT(_type = 'submit', _name = 'submit', 
                 _value = 'Submit', _class = "btn-submit"),
                 INPUT(_type = 'button', _value = 'Add field', 
                 _onClick = "$('<input type=text>').insertAfter(':input.string');", 
                 _class = "btn-warning")])
    if form.process().accepted:
        #do something
        pass
    elif form.errors:
        response.flash = 'Errors on form'
    return dict(form=form)
```

The code above adds fields dynamically but then seems complicate to retrieve the values and insert in database, I suppose that is what you want to do.

I think the following solution should work, just pass the number of needed fields as argument and on submit will insert all them.

If I haven't understood your request explain better please.

```
def add_person():
    fields = []
    for i in range(int(request.args(0) or 1)):
        fields.append(Field('person ' + str(i),
                      default='text ' + str(i)))

    form = SQLFORM.factory(*fields)
    if form.process().accepted:
        fields = [item[1] for item in form.vars.iteritems() 
                  if item[0].startswith('person')]
        for field in fields:
            db.people.insert(person=field)
    return dict(form=form)
```

Comment: No. I actually I want to add a list of people. So I need a button with + sign and when I click that it dynamically adds fields to the form.

Comment: Now I think I don't understand anymore... Say you have a table called people with a field called person. Every time you add a person to the table  you are creating a record, record1, record2...recordn.
Is this? You want to add many persons (records) at once?

Comment: @user have you found this answer useful?

Answer (score 0):

U cant add automatically fields to the form.It should be done Manually
Field('Name',label='',widget='').In this way u can add fields to the form

Answer (score 0):

Web2py allows you to do this easily. The only concession is that each time you use the form, you will end up with a list of persons in a single record.

If this can work for you, then change your model to this:

```
db.define_table("people", Field("person", "list:string"), format='%(person)s')
```

In your controller:

```
def add_persons():
    form = SQLFORM(db.people)
    if form.process().accepted:
        #do something
        pass
    elif form.errors:
        response.flash = 'Errors on form'
    return dict(form=form)
```

In the view template:

```
{{=form}}
```

This will display the form with a single field with + and - buttons beside it.
Whenever you add some text and click the + button or press Enter on your keyboard a new empty form field will be added below the existing one.

All this is possible because of how SQLFORM handles the "list:string" data type.